# Fixing axes ranges in pyplot subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, subplot

I am trying to plot data sets U(x,t) and V(x,t) using Python's matplotlib.pyplot subplots.  I want to manually set the axes of the first subplot, while the second subplot can choose its own axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(121)
plt.pcolor(xx,tt,U)
plt.colorbar()
plt.axes([0,600,0,100])
plt.subplot(122)
plt.pcolor(xx,tt,V)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

However, this seems to have no effect on changing the axes of the first subplot.  Also, after the plot generates, I get an extensive error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
...
...
raise LinAlgError('Singular matrix')
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

When I remove the above plotting commands from my code, however, the error disappears.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you share some sample data for xx, tt, U & V? So we can try running your example.

Comment: Sure!  As an example:

`from numpy import *`,
`xx = arange(0,700,30)`,
`tt = arange(0,100,5)`,
`U = outer(xx,tt)`,
`V = outer(xx**(1/2),tt/4)`.  I am no longer getting the error for some reason, but the plot is still wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks. With that example data I was getting "shape mismatch" errors. Note in the answer below I flipped the `xx` & `tt` order in the `pcolor` function calls to fix it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to set the axes itself, you can try adjusting the xlim and ylim properties instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
xx = arange(0,700,30)
tt = arange(0,100,5)
U = outer(xx,tt)
V = outer(xx**(1/2),tt/4)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.pcolor(tt,xx,U)
plt.colorbar()
#plt.axes([0,600,0,100])

plt.xlim(0,100)
plt.ylim(0,600)

plt.subplot(122)
plt.pcolor(tt,xx,V)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image: Script Output]